# Why Lm317 burnout and the potentiometer sparks?

Tags: lm317

so I tried to make a power supply using Lm317 
and it works fine when i used a 12 v transformer but when I used a 9-0-9 transformer like in the picture,when i turn potentiometer, it sparks and then 
the output become 23v and burnout .

here is the circuit that i used .

[image: Lm317 Schematic]

[image: transformer 9-0-9]

I don't know where the probem and I hope you can help me

Comment: How are you connecting the three secondary wires of the transformer to the two input terminals of the circuit?

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on how your circuit is connected to the transformer.

Comment: The wiper current rating of your potentiometer is not that great - can it take 50 mA through the wiper?

Comment: @Andyaka The wiper doesn't seem to even be connected, though that's a different problem.

Comment: Oh rest assured that it's connected else the pot wouldn't burn.

Comment: @Felthry I think that's just a  pin-out issue, Pin2 is normally the wiper.

Comment: I think pot was connected to input or output and you shorted it out.

Comment: i connected both red wires which gave me 18.5v and i didn't connect the black one. when i tried the  9v between red and black wires the circuit worked fine . when i connect the transformer to the circuit the lm317 short between pins 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

If your pot is of poor quality, any wiper break will cause a sudden high resistance that will have unfortunate consequences to the constant current driver in the regulator. Voltage on the wiper will spike to full input voltage and the output voltage will also spike at full on.

Use a better pot and add a capacitor across it as indicated in the spec sheet.

[image]

Even then, I would be tempted to add a fixed resistor across the pot so you know what the worst case will be if the wiper loses contact, or as Peter mentioned, wire the pot as shown below so the body of the pot is always presenting a resistance when the wiper breaks contact.

[image]

Comment: I would connect the pot so the full resistance element is always in-circuit, with the wiper connected to one end of the pot - that way, no extra components are required, and an open wiper connection will not leave the Adjust terminal floating.

Comment: Good add @PeterBennett